# Git Switch branch ignoring branch name case

Tags: git, git-branch

Is there any way to do `git switch` ignoring the case of the branch name?

So if I have the branch with name `QA`, this will not work

`git switch qa`

Is there any way to make it work?

I am actually making an automated tool where I switch branches of many repositories, so some of my repositories have branch name `qa` and some with name `QA` and so the global script does not work even though the repositories have same name

Comment: Perhaps you might grep the branches to know what that repo has before running the checkout? What you are asking for (having git take care of that _automagically_), I I'm sure it sounds like a simple thing.... but it will have a long tail if git wanted to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to do that.

Because git branch is case `sensitive`. That means you can actually have two different branch named `qa` and `QA`. They are completely two different branches.

- If I run the following commands, it will create two branches.

  ```sh
  $ git branch qa
  $ git branch QA
  ```
- Which I can confirm by running the following.

  ```sh
  $ git branch
    QA
  * master
    qa
  ```

So, you have to create all the branches with same `case` letter or you find out what branch that repo has and take action accordingly.

Comment: More precisely, Git's branch names are *meant* to be case sensitive. Due to an implementation quirk, the names are *sometimes* (but not always!) case insensitive on standard Windows and MacOS file systems. Git is having some work done on it to fix this so that the names will always be case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Though git doesn't provide us with the obvious way, there is a simple way to achieve this

you can use `grep` to solve your problem
`git checkout $(git branch | grep -iF "QA")`